# Xcode 14.3 Error: Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS for architecture arm64

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, mobile

Im having trouble with building my react native app, which is using Xcode 14.3 to build up properly. Im getting the following error code:

```
"In /Users/dan/Desktop/Work/Elbvillage/myfairleads_app/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector(FIRAnalyticsConnector_8094107d82c527bf23f93e98c9db96d1.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/dan/Desktop/Work/Elbvillage/myfairleads_app/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector' for architecture arm64"
```

Also:

```
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Kind regards